# frontend and backend design not working after create multi store for multi language

Tags: magento2.3, admin, frontend, backend

Hello I want to create multi language site in magento2. I have follow particular magento2 tutorial.[link that I have used](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-administration/create-multi-language-store-magento-2-part-2/). After I have follow command
1.php bin/magento indexer:reindex
2.php bin/magento cache:flush
3.php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4.php bin/magento cache:flush
5.php bin/magento setup:di:compile
6.php bin/magento cache:disable

to solve this issue I have given screenshot below for frontend and backend
front end
[image: frontenad]
back end
[image: backend]

Comment: did you run content-deploy command and given proper permissions to all magento folders?

Comment: what is your all store language and also admin user language ??

Comment: i have selected french language and create store of french.

Comment: i don't know about permission but i have run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-deploy-specific-language-in-magento-2/

Comment: I think you need it

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sosoUHn.png i have do but not working. i have create child theme of magento/Blank

Comment: any issue i set already merged css file yes and minify css yes

Answer (score 0):

**Run the below commnds,**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f en_US fr_FR
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qeOHgCk.png after hit below command it given this error

Comment: it's permission error , give the 777 permission of your magento root folder

Comment: mean i have magento2 folder so i have to set permission sudo chmod 777 magento2 it it right

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 magento2/

Comment: is it good option give hole project to 777 permission?

Comment: don't worry it's will nothing to happen anything alse, otherwise you will give the 777 permission to your generated pub and var folder of your magento.

Comment: i have set it but still not wroking. after running code same issue occur deisgn is not woking

Comment: how many store has a your website ??

Comment: i have to store two store default store view and antoher for french

Comment: now admin is  working ??

Comment: no admin is not working.

Comment: are you set the another language for admin ?

Comment: no i have not set another language i have follow this link https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-administration/create-multi-language-store-magento-2-part-2/

Comment: before i have set Merged css file and Minify css file to yes to it can be problem for me

Comment: what is your current mode of your site ?

Comment: Current application mode: default. for my site

Comment: set the developer mode after run the above commands

Comment: are you set the another language for admin user ?

Comment: no i have not set any laugange may permission issue with css file